# How to use additional parameters for PhantomJS in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, phantomjs, dockerfile

I have a docker container for PhantomJS. It works, but I can't put any params for phantomjs:

```
docker run —rm fizzka/phantomjs-source-capture http://phantomjs.org
```

it is work

```
docker run —rm fizzka/phantomjs-source-capture --proxy=185.72.225.18:3128 http://phantomjs.org
```

It doesn't work. How I can do it, and change my code?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM wernight/phantomjs
COPY src/printSource.js /
ENTRYPOINT ["phantomjs", "printSource.js"]

CMD ["--help"]
```

and my printSource.js

```
var system = require('system');

var url = system.args[1];

if (!url || url == '--help') {
    console.log("Usage: <docker-image-run> URL");
    phantom.exit();
}

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            // page.render(output);
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 2000);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The command you are trying to run ends up as:

```
phantomjs printSource.js --proxy=185.72.225.18:3128 http://phantomjs.org
```

However, from the [phantomjs cli ref](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) you need to pass your options (like `--proxy`) before the js file so that it's passed to phantomjs instead of your js script.

Comment: yes, thanks, but I thought put printSource.js into container, What do you think about it?

Comment: You can include it in the container, but when you define your entrypoint with that as the first argument, there's no way to add any other arguments before it. You'll need to redesign your entry point, possibly with a shell script, to pass your various arguments on the proper side of the js argument (e.g. `--help` still needs to go after). Or remove it from the entrypoint entirely and include printSource.js in your cli.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
FROM wernight/phantomjs
COPY src/printSource.js /
ENTRYPOINT ["phantomjs", "printSource.js", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "filename=filename", "sessionId=<sesssionId>", "domain=localhost", "url=<phantomjs host address>"]
```

this is how you can add more command arguments.